# Convert pymongo.cursor.Cursor to list is really slow

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, generator, database-cursor

I have a collection in MongoDB with 15k-20k data. However, converting the cursor to list takes 50 seconds for every 1000 cursor data. This has been running fast for three weeks, but today for some reason this has changed. Just to clarify, this has happened suddenly.

My question is:
Is it possible that pymongo is sending something in the cursor that generates this (freetier limitation)? What else could be causing it?

#### What I tried

```py
def find_all(self):
    yield self.collection.find(filter={}, projection={'_id': False}, batch_size=1000)#.skip(0).limit(1000)
```

##### How it looked before

```py
def find_all(self):
    return self.collection.find(filter={}, projection={'_id': False})

list(cursor)
```

#### MongoDB samples

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's freetier? A hosted DB? If so that's probably it.

Comment: @pguardiario cloud mongodb in atlas

Comment: They're likely throttling the network. Just upgrade or install a local db

Comment: @pguardiario yeah I tried so many things, but their docs doesnt say that. I'll try and let you know, thanks :)